# Using Pest.rs, how can I dump the contents of the stack?

Tags: rust, stack, pest

Pest.rs provides [different stack functions like `PUSH`](https://docs.rs/pest_derive/2.1.0/pest_derive/#push-pop-drop-and-peek). These *seem* to work for me, but I would like to know if there is a way to debug the stack operations? If things aren't going as planned, is there an easy way to trigger a debug operation such that I can see things `PUSH`'d and `POP`'d off the stack, or the current state after each stack operation?

I feel like developing with these functions is more brute force than I'd like.

Comment: Some tools have a convention - print extra debug information if a certain environment variable is set. I guess pest could use such a patch.